# type cast CryptoPP::Integer to int

Tags: c++, type-conversion, crypto++

I don't have any experience of Crypto++ library. In my project I need to typecast `Integer` to `int`. This is what I am trying:

```
int low_bound1=8;
int low_bound2=9;
Integer x=1,y=2;
low_bound1=(int)x;
low_bound1=(int)y;
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
error: invalid cast from type 'CryptoPP::Integer' to type 'int'
```

Is it possible to do? If yes then how?

Comment: It's a multi precision Integer (it can store values too large to hold in the built in types): has conversion methods: https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html  eg https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html#a2e90d8f4c5a13e203b94f9abc24d733f

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do? If yes then how?

Yes, it *may* possible to do, but not with a simple C-style cast.

Here is the documentation for the Integer class from the manual: [Integer Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html). Under the heading ***ACCESSORS***, there are two methods:

> `bool IsConvertableToLong () const`
>   Determines if the Integer is convertable to Long. More...
>
> `signed long ConvertToLong () const`
>   Convert the Integer to Long. More...

So you need to do something like:

```
int low_bound1, low_bound2;
Integer x=1,y=2;

if (x > std::numeric_limits<int>::max() || x < std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
    throw std::out_of_range("Integer x does not fit int data type");

if (y > std::numeric_limits<int>::max() || y < std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
    throw std::out_of_range("Integer y does not fit int data type");

low_bound1 = static_cast<int>(x.ConvertToLong());
low_bound2 = static_cast<int>(y.ConvertToLong());
```